# Sending Google Analytics events when the app is in the background on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

What is the behavior of google analytics when you send the events when the iOS app is moved to background. Do those events make it to the service ? Do we have to specifically call [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];  in those cases ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can definitely do as you suggested, with:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
```

There is a second on Google Analytics background dispatching [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch), which basically gives you this method:

```
// This method sends any queued hits when the app enters the background.
- (void)sendHitsInBackground {
  __block BOOL taskExpired = NO;

  __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskId =
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    taskExpired = YES;
  }];

  if (taskId == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
    return;
  }

  __weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;
  self.dispatchHandler = ^(GAIDispatchResult result) {
    // Send hits until no hits are left, a dispatch error occurs, or
    // the background task expires.
    if (result == kGAIDispatchGood && !taskExpired) {
      [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatchWithCompletionHandler:weakSelf.dispatchHandler];
    } else {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:taskId];
    }
  };

  [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatchWithCompletionHandler:self.dispatchHandler];
}
```

Override applicationDidEnterBackground, like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
  [self sendHitsInBackground];
}
```

And override applicationWillEnterForeground, like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
  // Restores the dispatch interval because dispatchWithCompletionHandler
  // has disabled automatic dispatching.
  [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 120;
}
```